# React Static function to React ES6

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

how to convert react static to react ES6

```
statics: {
    getInstanceCount: (function() {
        var count = 0;

        return function() {
            return ++count;
        };
    }())
}
```

and where i call this in react ES6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Static methods are declared using the `static` keyword:

```
let count = 0;

class Foo {
  static getInstanceCount() {
    return ++count;
  }
}
```

If you want to use an IIFE reduce the visibility of `count`, you can always assign static methods later to the constructor, like any other property:

```
class Foo {}

Foo.getInstanceCount = (function() {
  var count = 0;

  return function() {
    return ++count;
  };
}());
```